# Spark SQL UDF with multiple arg does not work as expected

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am working in Scala programming language. I want to extract certain fields from DataFrame Column -which has json string. I also have list of collection of StructType which tells which schema to extract from particular row. I need to extract different schema for different rows. The collection of schema will contain many rows but I need to fetch only one schema based on another column (same row) in the DataFrame. Here is my code.

```
  df = df.withColumn("data", from_json(col("data"), getSchemaUDF(col("name"), events)))
  .....
  private def getSchemaUDF : UserDefinedFunction = udf(getSchema _)

  private def getSchema(field: String, schemas : Map[String, StructType]): StructType = {
    val schema = schemas.filter(x => x._1 == field)
    require(schema.size == 1, s"Multiple schemas found for ${field}")
    schema.head._2
  }
```

But I get this error in this line:

```
   df = df.withColumn("data", from_json(col("data"), getSchemaUDF(col("name"), events)))

Error:(127, 83) type mismatch;
 found   : Map[String,org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType]
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
      df = df.withColumn("data", from_json(col("data"), getSchemaUDF(col("name"), events)))
```

Can someone please tell me how can I fix it? Or how can I achieve this?

Comment: `event` is the in memory collection?

Comment: You want to have different schema for each Row according to based on another column?

Comment: @koiralo: Yes different row can have different schema. I have a map of string, StructType. Here the key(String) is found in another column same row. I need to pick schema from map based on this value. So for each row, I need to pick one schema based on value of another column same row.